# Applying Find.Wrap in a specified Range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to check for inconsistencies in spelling between UK and US English, "aging"/"ageing" as an example, to display a message box if inconsistencies are found.

I need to only search for text in the main body of work, i.e., between the words Abstract and References (both in bold, so it only catches when used as headers).

`Wrap = wdFindContinue` seems to be extending the search outside of the range.
`Wrap = wdFindStop` doesn't work.
`wdFindAsk` is inappropriate for the use case.

```vb
Sub inconsistencyCheck()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Range
a = 0
b = 0

'search for abstract
    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "Abstract"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute
    End With
    
    myrange.Start = Selection.Start

'search for references
    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "References"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute
    End With

    myrange.End = Selection.Start
    myrange.Select

'search for inconsistencies
    With myrange.Find

        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute findtext:="aging"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        If .Found = True Then
            a = 1
        End If

        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute findtext:="ageing"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        If .Found = True Then
            b = 1
        End If
            
    End With

If a = 1 And b = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Both spellings of ageing found, please revise"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanatory comments in code below

```
Sub inconsistencyCheck()
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Range
    a = 0
    b = 0

    'search for abstract
    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "Abstract"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute
    End With
    
    myrange.Start = Selection.Start

    'search for references
    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "References"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute
    End With

    myrange.End = Selection.Start
    'myrange.Select

    'search for inconsistencies
    With myrange.Find
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True     'needs to be set before execution
        'myrange will be redefined to the found match if successful so subsequent find won't succeed
        'use a duplicate of myrange for the first execution.
        'Duplicate needs to be used first or you'll simply duplicate the found range
        If myrange.Duplicate.Find.Execute(findtext:="aging") Then a = 1
        If .Execute(findtext:="ageing") Then b = 1
        '.Format = True - not required you're trying to find text not formatting
        'not required as .Execute returns a boolean
        'If .Found = True Then
        '    a = 1
        'End If
'find parameters are already set so don't need to set them again
'        .MatchWholeWord = False
'        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
'        .Execute findtext:="ageing"
'        .Format = True
'        .Forward = True
'        If .Found = True Then
'            b = 1
'        End If
            
    End With

    If a = 1 And b = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Both spellings of ageing found, please revise"
    End If

End Sub
```

Rewritten as I would do it:

```
Sub inconsistencyCheck()
    Dim myrange As Range, findIn As Range
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Range

    'establish range to search
    With myrange.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        If .Execute(findtext:="Abstract") Then Set findIn = myrange.Duplicate
        myrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        myrange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
        If .Execute(findtext:="References") Then findIn.End = myrange.Start
    End With
    findIn.Select
    
    'search for inconsistencies
    With findIn.Find
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Forward = True
        If findIn.Duplicate.Find.Execute(findtext:="ageing") Then b = 1
        If .Execute(findtext:="aging") Then a = 1
    End With

    If a = 1 And b = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Both spellings of ageing found, please revise"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, thanks. Your example in the top works perfectly. I tried your second example, and it works, except the msgbox will still be triggered even if only "ageing" is found - any idea why that might be?

Comment: @timjack - If only one spelling is present I don't get the message box with either version.

Comment: That's odd, maybe a bug with my computer or my copy of Word. Oh well, the first one works perfectly and the explanations were all really useful, cheers again :)